# mysql if value exists in column else

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to use `if else` condition in `where` clause.

I have tried following query.

```
Set @msg = 'Member not on file.';

SELECT q.Id, q.ParentId, q.RootId FROM queues q 
Where 
CASE When q.Name = @msg Then 1
 else q.Name = 'EDI'
End;
```

Here I want to check If massage is exists in column i.e. `Name` then return `Id,ParentId, RootId` else return the `Id,ParentId,RootId` of `Name = 'EDI'`. 
When I run this it returns both result. In above code the `@msg` i.e. `'Member not on file.'` is already is in table. If @msg is not exists then **only** I want return the **id's** of **EDI**.

How can I improve the query?

Answer (score 0):

I never used CASE-Statements on MySQL Server, only MS SQL Server.
I guess, you don't have a proper comparison in WHERE clause.
In your statement above you will always run in Case When, so your Statement ist

```
SELECT q.Id, q.ParentID, q.RootId FROM queues q
WHERE 1
```

As 1 is always true, so you get bot results.

Maybe this one fits your needs?

```
SELECT q.Id, q.ParentId, q.RootId FROM queues q
WHERE q.Name = CASE WHEN q.Name = @msg THEN @msg ELSE 'EDI'
```

So you will have q.Name=@msg OR q.Name='EDI', depeding on  the value of q.Name.

Comment: It still return both record. Record for matching `Name` as well as EDI

Comment: Could you tell more about the problem? If you always want to show only datarows with name = '@msg' if @msg exists in the table, rcs' answer should match. Otherwise it would be great to know more about what you are trying to do to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM queues q Where q.Name = @msg) > 0 THEN
    SELECT q.Id, q.ParentId, q.RootId FROM queues q Where q.Name = @msg
ELSE
    SELECT q.Id, q.ParentId, q.RootId FROM queues q Where q.Name = 'EDI'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `union` and `not exists` to achieve it something as

```
select * from queues where Name = @msg 
union 
select * from queues 
where Name = 'EDI' 
and  not exists (select 1 from queues q1 where q1.Name = @msg);
```